# Why am i seeing the full post request url in my POST header?

Tags: http, url, post, https, header

I have a login endpoint that i monitor and every so often i get different results on the requests to it. Sometimes i see the path in the POST method header whilst at other times I see the full url

here is an example of a connection with the full url in the POST

```
POST https://example.com/services/auth/login   HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Origin: https://example.com
Referer: https://example.com/123/login.xhtml
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Te: trailers
Connection: close
cookie: <>
```

What i expect to see is something like:

```
POST /services/auth/login   HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Origin: https://example.com
```

I can't narrow it down to the proxy (yet) but is it normal?

Comment: The full request URL is usually contained in HTTP 2 requests, not in HTTP 1.1 requests as in your example.

Comment: Where do you see this?

Comment: I see this in my firewall - so maybe its a parsing issue there?